# c++ istream operator >>

Tags: c++, matrix, istream, ostream

I have some problem with my operator >>

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, Matrix& M) {

    char first;

    is>>first;


    for(int i = 0;i<M.rows();i++) {

        for(int j = 0;j<M.cols();j++) {

            is>>M[i][j];
            cout<<M[i][j];

        }

        is>>first;

    }

    return is;
}
```

I want to the size of the istream operator because I want to change the for loops so that they don't depend on the Matrix that was sent in i.e. is you send in a matrix with the size 1 and the stream `[1 2 3 4; 4 5 6 7; 1 2 3 4]` then a new matrix with the size(3*4) should be constructed. so that i can use the assignment-operator to assign it to matrix M.

In other words, the stream is on the form `"[ 1 2 3; 2 3 4; 4 5 6]"` and ; means new row.
I want to know how many rows and cols there are.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the rows like this:

```
vector<string> rows;
string line;

is.ignore(INT_MAX, '['); // ignores all characters until it passes a [

while (std::getline(is, line, ';'))
    rows.push_back(line); // put each row in rows

rows.back().erase(rows.back().find(']')); // erase the ending ]
```

Now you have each row string in `rows`, then

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i) {
    vector<int> items;
    istringstream strstm(rows[i]);

    std::copy(istream_iterator<int>(strstm), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(items));

    // now items is full of the entries, resize the matrix to hold items.size()
    // many items and insert each one into it, or whatever
}
```

Comment: I get this error : variable ‘std::istringstream strstm’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: @shizzle: You need to `#include <sstream>`.

Answer (score 1):

First, of course, you'll need to specify things a bit stricter than you
have.  What should you do with something like `"[ 11 12 13; 21 22; 31 32
33 ]"`, for example: insert a `0.0` for the missing value, or set
`failbit`?

Beyond that, using `std::vector` to collect the input will make things a 
bit easier.  Something like the following, for example:

```
template< typename T >
char getRow( std::istream& source, std::vector<T>& dest )
{
    dest.clear();
    char separator;
    source >> separator;
    while ( source && separator != ';' && separator != ']' ) {
        source.unget();
        T tmp;
        source >> tmp;
        if ( source ) {
            dest.push_back( tmp );
            source >> separator;
        }
    }
    if ( source && dest.empty() ) {
        dest.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    }
    return source ? separator : '\0';
}

template< typename T >
char getFirstRow( std::istream& source,
                  std::vector<std::vector<T> >& dest )
{
    dest.clear();
    std::vector<T> row;
    char separator = getRow( source, row );
    if ( source ) {
        if ( row.empty() ) {
            dest.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        } else {
            dest.push_back( row );
        }
    }
    return source ? separator : '\0';
}

template< typename T >
char getFollowingRow( std::istream& source,
                 std::vector<std::vector<T> >& dest )
{
    std::vector<T> row;
    char separator = getRow( source, row );
    if ( source ) {
        if ( row.size() != dest.front().size() ) {
            dest.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit ) ;
        } else {
            dest.push_back( row );
        }
    }
    return source ? separator : '\0';
}

template< typename T >
std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, Matrix<T>& dest )
{
    char separator;
    source >> separator;
    if ( separator != '[' ) {
        source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    } else {
        std::vector<std::vector<T> > results;
        separator = getFirstRow( source, results );
        while ( separator == ';' ) {
            separator = getFollowingRow( source, results );
        }
        if ( separator != ']' ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        }
        if ( source ) {
            dest.assign( results );
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

Of course, this means that the `Matrix<T>::assign` function must be able
to set the dimensions.  And to be usable, `Matrix<T>` needs a default
constructor, which probably "defers" actual construction until
`Matrix<T>::assign`.

Also: we're somewhat limited in the above by the limited possibilities
for error reporting in iostreams.  In particular, we'd really like to
distinguish between input like `"[11 12 13; 21"` and nothing (a true end
of file condition).  But our attempts to read the separator after `"21"`
will set `eofbit`, and there's nothing we can do about it.  (Actually,
we *could* create a new status word, using `std::ios_base::xalloc()`,
setting it if, and only if, the read of `'['` at the start fails with
`eofbit` set.  But this would require a very unstandard way of checking
for errors in client code, which would in turn create an endless stream
of maintenance problems.)

Finally, two meta-comments: if this seems complicated... it is.  Input
is almost always complicated, because of all of the various error
conditions you have to check.  And second, note the use of functions to
keep each individual operation (sort of) simple.  It's a frequent
mistake of beginners to not break things down like this—it's
almost always poor programming, for example, to have a nested loop in a
function, except when applying mathematical algorithms to things like
`Matrix`.  In this case, parsing is not a mathematical algorithm, and
you want to separate the handling of each row from the overall handling;
in this case, it's also useful to separate the handling of the first row
from the others, since the error cases are different.  (The first row
can have any length greater than 0, later rows must have the same length
as the previous rows.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the stream-extraction operator requires an already constructed object that it can modify. You have to adapt your matrix-class so that it can be resized dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to determine the "size of istream operator", since it is, well, stream, and when you read the first matrix element, no one can guarantee that the last element already exists. You should at first read the whole string, and then parse it and extract information about size of input matrix. After that, you can use your code by supplying this string to it via `stringstream`. Of course, you have to be able to dynamically change the size of the matrix.